# Solving Non-Linear Differential Equation Sympy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

This code only works for solving the differential equation v_equation if v(t) isn't squared. When I squared it it returned the error PolynomialDivisionFailed. Is there another way of doing this with Sympy or should I find a different python package for doing these sorts of calculations.

```
from sympy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = float(raw_input('Mass:\n> '))
g = 9.8
k = float(raw_input('Drag Coefficient:\n> '))
f1 = g * m
t = Symbol('t')
v = Function('v')
v_equation = dsolve(f1 - k * (v(t) ** 2) - m * Derivative(v(t)), 0)
C1 = Symbol('C1')
C1_ic = solve(v_equation.rhs.subs({t:0}),C1)[0]
v_equation = v_equation.subs({C1:C1_ic})

func = lambdify(t, v_equation.rhs,'numpy')
```

Comment: What values are you using for `m` and `k`? This works for me for some test values in SymPy 1.0.

Comment: @asmeurer I was using m = 96 and k = .2. For which values did it work?

Comment: I see. That fails for me too. I opened an issue at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11542 for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience with symbolic math packages, I would not recommend performing (symbolic) calculations using floating point constants. It is better to define equations using symbolic constants, perform calculations as far as possible, and then substitute with numerical values.

With this approach, Sympy can provide a solution for this D.E.

First, define symbolic constants. To aid calculations, note that we can provide additional information about these constants (e.g., real, positive, e.t.c)

```
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols('t', real = True)
g, k, m = sp.symbols('g, k, m', real = True, positive = True)
v = sp.Function('v')
```

The symbolic solution for the DE can be obtained as follows

```
f1 = g * m
eq = f1 - k * (v(t) ** 2) - m * sp.Derivative(v(t))
sol = sp.dsolve(eq,v(t)).simplify()
```

The solution `sol` will be a function of `k`, `m`, `g`, and a constant `C1`. In general, there will be two, complex `C1` values corresponding to the initial condition. However, both values of `C1` result in the same (real-valued) solution when substituted in `sol`.

Note that if you don't need a symbolic solution, a numerical ODE solver, such as Scipy's `odeint`, may be used. The code would be the following (for an initial condition `0`):

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def fun(v, t, m, k, g):
    return (g*m - k*v**2)/m

tn = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
soln = odeint(fun, 0, tn, args=(1000, 0.2, 9.8))
```

`soln` is an array of samples `v(t)` corresponding to the `tn` elements

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Also, would I able to have the solution to the differential equation be returned as a function using scipy?

Comment: @KKlj8 In principle, the answer is no, scipy (and any other *numerical* solver), can only provide samples of a function corresponding to a finite set of values of the independent variable. However, you can always use this set of samples as a basis for setting up a function that provides values for any other (arbitrary) value of the independent variable by means of [interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html).